# Mysql import error in various methods

Tags: php, mysql

[image]I wanted to launch my remote site with localhost for development purpose. My remote site is running under Mysql/mangento.

I tied with various methods to import my database backup to a new database at localhost, it shows error

Via PHPmyadmin,

MySQL said: Documentation
**#1367 - Illegal double '1.79769313486232e+308' value found during parsing**

From the command prompt

**"ERROR 1367 (22007) at line 10543: Illegal double '1.79769313486232e+308' value found during parsing"**

Attaching a screenshot for reference.

Comment: posible duplicate of: [Illegal double value found during parsing](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7885/error-on-import-of-mysqldump-file-illegal-double-value-found-during-parsing)

Comment: actually it is working in production. Tried after creating new blankDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is better described here:
   [mysql]http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=44995

And the solution is to replace 1.79769313486232e+308 with \'1.79769313486232e+308\'.